# XML package in R - readHTMLTable and multiple row classes

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I'm trying to scrape data from this website [Extra Skater](http://www.extraskater.com/team/montreal-canadiens/2012/gamelog)

into a data frame. From what I can tell looking at the HTML code, there are multiple row classes through which you can toggle to display different table rows. I'm only interested in the rows which have the label:

```
<tr class="team-game-stats team-game-stats-5v5close hidden">
```

For example:

```
<tr class="team-game-stats team-game-stats-5v5close hidden">
    <td class="hidden">5v5close</td>

    <td><a href="/game/2013-01-19-maple-leafs-canadiens">2013-01-19: Maple Leafs 2 at Canadiens 1</a></td>

    <td class="number-right">19.7</td>
    <td class="number-right">0</td>
    <td class="number-right">0</td>
    <td class="number-right">14</td>    
    <td class="number-right">18</td>
    <td class="number-right">43.8%</td>
    <td class="number-right">11</td>
    <td class="number-right">15</td>
    <td class="number-right">42.3%</td>
    <td class="number-right">8</td>
    <td class="number-right">11</td>
    <td class="number-right">42.1%</td>
    <td class="number-right">0.0%</td>
    <td class="number-right">100.0%</td>

</tr>
```

When I run the code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
theurl <- "http://www.extraskater.com/team/montreal-canadiens/2012/gamelog"
tb = readHTMLTable(theurl)
```

It returns a list with all the table rows stacked one on top of the other. I imagine that I have to use xpathSApply to have more precision, but I am unsure about the path argument. When I run the code:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

theurl <- "http://www.extraskater.com/team/montreal-canadiens/2012/gamelog"
webpage <- getURL(theurl)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)

pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

# Extract table header and contents
results <- xpathSApply(pagetree, "//*/table[@class='team-game-stats team-game-stats-5v5close hidden']/tr/td", xmlValue)
```

results return as NULL.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
xxpath = "//*[@class='team-game-stats team-game-stats-5v5close hidden']"
xpathApply(pagetree,xxpath,readHTMLList)
```

Comment: That works. All I had to do was use as.data.frame to get it into the format I wanted.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Could you just filter the data.frame rather than the HTML?

```
tb <- readHTMLTable(theurl, which=1)
table(tb$Situation)
     5v5 5v5close  5v5tied      all       ev       pp       sh 
      48       48       48       48       48       48       48 
subset(tb, Situation=="5v5close")
```